# How to include a calendar management module easily within a Django project

Tags: python, django, calendar

I am developing a Python Django platform, using Django, html, and a bit a javascript. This platform aims to manage bookings.

I am stuck on a calendar module which I could insert within my html pages. The calendar module would read schedule availabilties and redirect to a booking page when clicked on it.

Ideally, I would like something similar to this website : https://www.doctolib.fr/medecin-generaliste/paris (class 'dl-search-result-calendar'). I know it might be coded in AngularJS and Ajax, although my knowledge of this 2 technos is very limited.

My question is, what would be the easiest solution to insert such a calendar module, with booking redirect module ?

Any help is welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if working hour in one shift 
you can create model to store unavailable time (reserved time)
and render any time not in this model to new booking.

you can solve it in many way, hope my answer suits you.

Comment: Thanks, any specific JS or other to display it ?